# how to align pop up menu items to the right and make it rtl?

Tags: android, material-design, right-to-left

im new in android development and im working on material design.
i've made a pop up menu in toolbar but i want the item aligned in right because im using a rtl language. How should i do it.
here is s screenshot.[screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryseI.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!  You're more likely to get an answer if you write a good question.  For example, can you include the code/xml that you wrote to display the pop-up menu?  What have you tried to fix your problem, and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the line `android:supportsRtl="true"` to your AndroidManifest file inside the tag `application`?
For some reason right-to-left only works for me if I set it to `false`.
If I set `true` the right-to-left-language texts are shown right-to-left, but the items in the Menu are left-to-right.